What is the chance a Spectral card appears in an Arcana Pack after getting Omen Globe?
The description of the Omen Globe voucher says:

Spectral cards may appear in any of the Arcana Packs.

What are the odds of getting a Spectral card when opening an Arcana Pack after buying the Omen Globe voucher?


Guessing 0.3% due to the Wiki on Spectral Cards:

The chance of each Spectral card appearing is equal, except for The Soul and Black Hole. These two can only be found in Booster Packs, with the Spectral and Arcana packs being able to contain The Soul, and Spectral and Celestial packs being able to contain Black Hole. Both have a 0.3% chance to appear for every card found in one of their respective Booster Packs.

